# How to add UITabBarController programatically without using AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I want to put a UITabBar in two views, but not in the MainViewController, because I am not using the AppDelegate to put it.

Is there a solution without .xib or storyboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UIViewController *vc1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
vc1.title = @"FIRST";
vc1.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

UIViewController *vc2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
vc2.title = @"SECOND";
vc2.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

UITabBarController *tabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBar.viewControllers = @[vc1,vc2];
tabBar.selectedIndex   = 1;
tabBar.view.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 220, 320);

[tabBar willMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self.view addSubview:tabBar.view];
[self addChildViewController:tabBar];
[tabBar didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Comment: Should I put that in my MainViewController ?

Comment: put it where you want to add tabBar

Comment: Thank you but where can i put items actions ?

Comment: hey you can put items action in same controller where you add tabbar