# iOS how to add tabbar in second screen of application?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I want to make application in which first is login screen and i diidnot want tabbar in it As i want tabbar from second screen .But when i write tabbar code in appdelegate it also comes in login screen . So how to code it ?

Comment: Hey check this link where i gave answer.It seems close to your problem.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22195806/how-to-add-uitabbarcontroller-programatically-without-using-appdelegate/22195874#22195874

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your controller screen where you want add TabBar

```
UIViewController *vc1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
vc1.title = @"FIRST";
vc1.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

UIViewController *vc2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
vc2.title = @"SECOND";
vc2.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

UITabBarController *tabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBar.viewControllers = @[vc1,vc2];
tabBar.selectedIndex   = 1;
tabBar.view.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 220, 320);

[tabBar willMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self.view addSubview:tabBar.view];
[self addChildViewController:tabBar];
[tabBar didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Comment: this tabbar view is coming on top of my second screen.so what should i do.?

Comment: Top of second view ??? it will appear according the dimensions set tab bar dimension according your requirement by simply changing tab bar.view.frame

Answer (score 1):

If you are using storyboard, then I would suggest the following method:

Drag a `UIViewController` and embed it around a `UINavigationController`. This will be your LoginViewController containing username, password and login button.

Now add a `UITabbarController` onto storyboard and give its `Storyboard Id` as 'mainTab'- for holding your tab items.

Now just hook up the login button click from LoginViewController and add the following line of code when you want to logged in to your tab bar controller.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UITabBarController *obj=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainTab"];
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
```

Yes, its assuming that your storyboard's name is MainStoryboard.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Show your login screen from appDelegate. Then from login viewController show the second viewController with tabBar. Use following code.

```
//create a UITabBarController object
UITabBarController *tabBarController=[[UITabBarController alloc]init];

//FirstViewController and SecondViewController are the view controllers you want on your UITabBarController (Number of view controllers can be according to your need)
FirstViewController *firstViewController=[[FirstViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
SecondViewController *secondViewController=[[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

//adding view controllers to your tabBarController bundling them in an array
tabBarController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstViewController,secondViewController, nil];

//navigating to the UITabBarController that you created
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];
```